# InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

So Ive got a problem with my code where I try and set a google street view position from a variable that i downloaded from a database. The database and php side of it works but when I try and assign it to the "panorama.setPosition(prizeLocation);" it gives me the error "InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object". Ive tried and have a look around but everyone has problems with setCenter and not with setPosition. Any help is appreciated

Thanks

HTML Code:

```
<script>
var prizeLocation;
function downloadCoords() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'prizeCoordsTransformer.php',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            prizeLocation = data.prizeLocation;
            console.log(prizeLocation);
        },
        error: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        }
    }); 
}
</script
```

(later down the script)

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(prizeLocation);
    panorama = map.getStreetView();
    panorama.setPosition(prizeLocation);
    panorama.setPov({
        heading: 265,
        pitch: 0
    });
    panorama.setVisible(true);
    panorama.setOptions({
        fullscreen: true,
        enableCloseButton: false
    });
}, 2000);
</script>
```

PHP Code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 0); 
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "db";

 // Create connection
 $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
 mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);

 // Check connection
 if (!$conn) 
 {
   die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
 }
 // echo "Connected successfully";


 $query = "SELECT prizeLocation FROM prizeLocation";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
 $result1 = mysqli_fetch_row($result);



echo json_encode(array('prizeLocation'=>$result1[0]));

mysqli_close($conn); 

?>
```

P.S. Everything here works perfectly but the prizeLocation variable. so if i were to change the variable to "var prizeLocation = {lat: -43.533476, lng: 172.636581};" or something it would work

Comment: Does the console.log(prizeLocation); in the success print a string or an object

Comment: @mplungjan an object

Answer (score 2):

1. Does the PHP set the mime type `application/json` ?
2. Does the console.log(prizeLocation); in the success print a string or an object - if still a string, do `prizeLocation = JSON.parse(data.prizeLocation);`
3. The object should be `{"lat": -43.533476, "lng": 172.636581}`

Like this

```js
   var pl = {"lat": -43.533476, "lng": 172.636581};
   console.log(pl);
```

Try this

```
<?PHP
header("content-type:application/Json");
$arr = array('lat' => -43.533476, 'lng' => 172.636581);
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: 1. Yes 2. I tried that and I get this error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in JSON at position 0" that may be because in the php i do this " echo json_encode(array('prizeLocation'=>$result1[0]));"

Comment: Object {prizeLocation: "lat: -43.533476, lng: 172.636581"}

Comment: The object should be in the format `{"lat": -43.533476, "lng": 172.636581}`

Comment: still no luck. i may have done it wrong tho, did u mean it should only read {"lat": -43.533476, "lng": 172.636581} or did u mean it should read Object {prizeLocation : "lat": -34.533476, "lng": 172.636581}

Comment: hmm do you have any idea how i could do that?

Comment: i dont think that would work because im downloading my prizeLocation from a mysql database and i will update my post with my php script